# How do I remove nans from a 3d array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

I am struggling to remove nans from only the first axis in a 3D array:

```
#random 3d array
arr = np.random.rand(100,22,65)

# adding some nans into the 3d Array
drops = np.random.rand(arr.shape[0])
arr[drops>.6] = np.nan 

print(arr)

[[[0.50460387 0.20243512 0.40565851 ... 0.3295956  0.08706913 0.86982205]
  [0.55801807 0.81047187 0.54865547 ... 0.11928294 0.15611051 0.46059784]
  [0.9498903  0.53928372 0.7283197  ... 0.13523853 0.74978296 0.09199356]
  ...
  [0.38572816 0.40296235 0.74567554 ... 0.80255748 0.73557092 0.41000921]
  [0.84826547 0.28085185 0.64373182 ... 0.59532477 0.38477439 0.18459691]
  [0.65145309 0.04609677 0.66094281 ... 0.73223061 0.62228023 0.77209647]]

 [[       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
  [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
  [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
  ...
  [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
  [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]
  [       nan        nan        nan ...        nan        nan        nan]]

 [[0.38894944 0.31905978 0.18022507 ... 0.55403955 0.5249038  0.56555038]
  [0.08681818 0.33565706 0.81498892 ... 0.9143682  0.90990995 0.63021248]
  [0.13032013 0.6853396  0.92230732 ... 0.50103541 0.99088708 0.16936173]
  ...
  [0.12723576 0.41259082 0.51133911 ... 0.25776505 0.53270183 0.11370443]
  [0.66122784 0.55920824 0.8898942  ... 0.21419021 0.70628061 0.38911146]
  [0.12346024 0.48609013 0.4320568  ... 0.39437054 0.39710332 0.14798718]]

 ...

 [[0.8156661  0.71134592 0.8722239  ... 0.82675182 0.33937164 0.61019577]
  [0.49977997 0.09878727 0.14879814 ... 0.04459504 0.95812556 0.64271129]
  [0.59579251 0.77436586 0.90238691 ... 0.52588061 0.90441973 0.52735465]
  ...
  [0.62507284 0.31856694 0.71666369 ... 0.99053521 0.46493073 0.58261624]
  [0.26170807 0.6870913  0.37371692 ... 0.52510082 0.80228438 0.78225314]
  [0.637483   0.02070607 0.10368726 ... 0.36134968 0.41236324 0.25692167]]
```

I tried this:

```
vals_no_nans = arr[~np.isnan(arr).any(axis=0)]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-469-f95817b5dc6d> in <module>()
      1 arr = np.random.rand(100,22,65)
      2 
----> 3 vals_no_nans = arr[~np.isnan(arr).any(axis=0)]

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 100 but corresponding boolean dimension is 22
```

I also tried :

```
no_nans = arr[~np.isnan(arr).any(axis=0)].reshape(-1, arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2])
```

but I still get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-471-039dc8ae2cab> in <module>()
      3 #vals_no_nans = arr[~np.isnan(arr).any(axis=0)]
      4 
----> 5 no_nans = arr[~np.isnan(arr).any(axis=0)].reshape(-1, arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2])

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 100 but corresponding boolean dimension is 22
```

How do I just remove nans from one axis (axis = 0) in a 3D array?

I also tried dropna() but it is not working, just returns empty array....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to drop "rows" which contain any nans? If so:

```py
keep = ~np.isnan(arr).any(axis=(-1, -2))
arr[keep]  # shape still (100, 22, 65)
```

How about another example:

```py
arr = np.arange(5*2*2).reshape((5,2,2)).astype(float)
arr[arr == 4] = np.nan
```

```
array([[[ 0.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  3.]],

       [[nan,  5.],
        [ 6.,  7.]],

       [[ 8.,  9.],
        [10., 11.]],

       [[12., 13.],
        [14., 15.]],

       [[16., 17.],
        [18., 19.]]])
```

```
keep = ~np.isnan(arr).any(axis=(-1, -2))
arr[keep]
```

```
array([[[ 0.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  3.]],

       [[ 8.,  9.],
        [10., 11.]],

       [[12., 13.],
        [14., 15.]],

       [[16., 17.],
        [18., 19.]]])
```